# Javascript removing listbox item only working first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I am just trying to check the amount of items in my ASP ListBox.

If the item count is greater than 10, then I remove the item at the 11th element.

It works the first time, but afterwards, only the item count correctly executes.

The lstEms.remove(10) no longer removes the item at the eleventh element.

I tried to null lstEms at the end of the function but that didn't do anything.

```
function countselected() {
    var lstEms = document.getElementById("<%= lstBox.ClientID %>");
    var selOpts = $("#ASP_lstBox")[0].length;
    console.log(selOpts);
    if (selOpts > 10) {
        alert("Cannot add more than 10 recipients");
        lstEms.remove(10);
        var newOpts = $("#ASP_lstBox")[0].length;
        alert(newOpts);
    };
};
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBox" runat="server" Height="90px" Width="219px"></asp:ListBox>
```

UPDATE 2:

Here is my CodeBehind that is calling the script:

```
protected void btn_AddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBox.Items.Add(item);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "", "countselected()", true); 
    }
```

Comment: The id is unique on your html page?

Comment: yeah, i just replaced it with a generic ID, but it is unique @R3tep

Comment: maybe post a fiddle to help demonstrate?

Comment: @blink-fish tbh, i have yet to test any js out on fiddle.. but from Firebug and my asp project, after the 2nd countselected() call, it still gives the correct item count @ alert(newOpts) but lstEms.remove(10) does not remove an item.

Comment: You are making a check against different element and removing item from different element. That's not good practice.

Comment: also provide your HTML mark up

Comment: @AnkushJain not sure how my ASP markup will help. it is simply an ASP ListBox.

Comment: It will help for sure. Just view source and provide it.

Comment: @AnkushJain as you can see, it's added, but I did provide some of my CodeBehind as that is where I am calling the script

Comment: If everything works fine, but the lstEms.remove.. perhaps put the debugger on lstEms and see what it is.  Additionally, you could look at doing a jquery remove
 `$("select#ASP_lstBox option:eq(10)").remove()`

Comment: @blink-fish i'll try to jQuery.. Firebug didn't pick up anything on the lstEms.remove(10). thanks

Comment: @blink-fish unfortunately that did not work, but what i thing i noticed was that console.log(selOpts); the number of items keeps incrementing, which is probably what's creating an error. It keeps trying to remove(10) but the next attempted item addition is at element(11) instead of (10).

Comment: @blink-fish one thing i discovered was that lstEms.remove() doesn't actually remove the ListBox item. After adding a second item past the max count, the first item (added after max) reappears.

Comment: I think we'd just be guessing now.  The best course of action in my opinion would be to isolate the code and the rendered HTML (no ASP).  Put it in a fiddle and reproduce the behavior.  That will help with 2 things, 1: we can rule out some odd ASP behavior, 2: someone will be able see a working sample of your problem and be able to fix it on the spot.

Comment: @blink-fish thanks for all the suggestions.